# Append to route collection

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have the following route data

```
object newsRoute = new
{
    Area = "Admin",
    Controller = "News",
    Action = "Edit"
}
```

How can I append Title = "Hello" to the object routNews?
As in or similar

```
newsRoute.Append(Title = "Hello");
```

Comment: Whats wrong with using the `ViewBag` property as the template does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create the anonymous object you've effectively defined the properties of the anonymous class. I don't think you'll have much luck trying to redefine the type after the fact. You could create a new anonymous object with the new field and the original fields and copy the fields over, but I'm guessing you wouldn't want to do this.

You say that the object represents routedata, in that case it is probably a good idea to convert the anonymous object into a RouteValueDictionary instance using the following method

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.htmlhelper.anonymousobjecttohtmlattributes(v=VS.98).aspx

Once converted the object has normal dictionary semantics so you can add new key value pairs at will.

You should then be able to use the RouteValueDictionary to generate your urls

Comment: Spot on! As we say in the land of oz. Fan-bloody-tastic!